# How to specify variable-length tuple of specific type in traits?

Tags: python, traits, enthought

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, Str, Tuple
    
class Data(HasTraits):

    values = Tuple(Str, ...)


data = Data(values=("a", "b", "c"))
```

Output:

```
TraitError: The 'values' trait of a Data instance must be a tuple of the form: (a string, an ellipsis or None), but a value of ('a', 'b', 'c') <class 'tuple'> was specified.
```

I am learning traits api and read the docs, I didn't a find way to pass any specific type to the variable-length tuple in traits. I am getting error! How do i solve this?

Changed `values = Tuple(Str, ...)` to `values = Tuple(Str)`, Still got:

```
TraitError: The 'values' trait of a Data instance must be a tuple of the form: (a string), but a value of ('a', 'b', 'c') <class 'tuple'> was specified.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Tuple docs](https://docs.enthought.com/traits/traits_api_reference/trait_types.html#traits.trait_types.BaseTuple), variable length tuples are not an option:

> The default value is determined as follows:
>
> 1. If no arguments are specified, the default value is ().
> 2. If a tuple is specified as the first argument, it is the default value.
> 3. If a tuple is not specified as the first argument, the default value is a tuple whose length is the length of the argument list, and whose values are the default values for the corresponding trait types.

The use case you're describing, a variable-length sequence of a single type is what you get with a `List(Str)`, although you do not get immutability. You could fake it, by creating a Property that gets and sets tuples but stores a List under the cover:

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, List, Str, Tuple, Property

class Foo(HasTraits):
    t_prop = Property(Tuple)
    _data = List(Str)
    
    def _get_t_prop(self):
        return tuple(self._data)
    
    def _set_t_prop(self, value):
        self._data = list(value)


foo = Foo()
foo.t_prop = ('a',)
print(foo.t_prop)
foo.t_prop = ('a', 'b')
print(foo.t_prop)
foo.t_prop = ('a', 'b', 1)
print(foo.t_prop)
```

This produces the output below. It's not quite right because the error message is triggered by the List validator, not the Tuple's.

```
('a',)
('a', 'b')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
traits.trait_errors.TraitError: Each element of the '_data' trait of a Foo instance must be a string, but a value of 1 <class 'int'> was specified.
```

You *could* validate the Tuple type with something like the following, but this starts feeling a little icky:

```
def _set_t_prop(self, value):
        validator = Tuple((Str, ) * len(value))
        validator.validate(self, "t_prop", value)
        self._data = list(value)
```

The generated output is:

```
('a',)
('a', 'b')
traits.trait_errors.TraitError: The 't_prop' trait of a Foo instance must be a tuple of the form: (a string, a string, a string), but a value of ('a', 'b', 1) <class 'tuple'> was specified.
```

Answer (score 0):

I can take a stab at this, although my Traits-fu is not what it once was.

You're hoping that Traits will validate a `Tuple` trait in the same way it validates `List` traits, and unfortunately that is the rub.  The contents of `Tuples` are not validated.  I *think* this is because `List`s are mutable and `Tuple`s are immutable, so there's an expectation that the values of a `List` will change (and thus need validation) and that the values of a `Tuple` will not, thus the `Tuple` trait does not carry the weight of the validation mechanism.

With that in mind, specifying `values = Tuple(Str, ...)` doesn't mean what you think it would mean based on how `list_values = List(Str)` behaves.

Consider these two classes:

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, List, Str, Tuple

class Foo(HasTraits):
    t_values = Tuple(Str)

class Bar(HasTraits):
    l_values = List(Str)

f = Foo(t_values=(1,2,3))
b = Bar(l_values=[1,2,3])
```

They should both trigger validation errors.  Note the difference in errors that you get for each one:

```
TraitError: The 't_values' trait of a Foo instance must be a tuple of the form: (a string), but a value of (1, 2, 3) <class 'tuple'> was specified.
```

Traits expects `t_values` to be "a tuple of the form: (a string)"

```
TraitError: Each element of the 'l_values' trait of a Bar instance must be a string, but a value of 1 <class 'int'> was specified.
```

This is the normal validation error you expect when specifying the wrong type.